# Inspect/sniff unencyrpted packets on my local network between 2 devices

Tags: networking, router, sniffing

Long story short I'm trying to reverse engineer an app that makes http (not ssl) requests to my TV to tinker with some home automation.

I spoofed my TVs mac address and switched to it's IP while the app was open and got a slew of useful stuff but the app soon errored out after my laptop wasn't responding how the TV would. I could play the game of simulating every call but that would take ages.

Is there a way I can inspect all the packets going between these 2 devices on my home network? I have a fancy ASUS router I could drop a custom firmware onto or ssh into and maybe run some basic commands if the router's linux os has it.

Comment: Does it have `tcpdump` installed?

Comment: Have you tried using wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put some device between whatever your app is running on (Smartphone? PC?) and the TV. Assuming you really mean LAN (ethernet) and not WLAN, that device needs to have at least two ethernet ports.

Setup the device to act as DCHP server and gateway, forward the traffic between the two devices, use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to sniff the traffic.

In principle, your ASUS router can act as such a device, however routers usually don't have enough main memory and/or flash memory (as harddisk substitute) to reliably record a lot of traffic, so if you try to use it, you'll likely loose some of the packets.

It's easy to use a Linux PC or laptop as such a device (Linux distributions have all the software you need ready to install), and I guess you could make it work on Windows, too.